# Loading nib into NSScrollView

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am trying to implement a view with no horizontal scrolling (will resize up and down) and variable vertical scrolling.

I've trying to do it by embedding the view on a scroll view in the storyboard and after a lot of fiddling got it working mostly but the content is all hidden outside the window so I never see it while editing so I thought I'd put the content in a separate nib file and load it onto the scroll view.

I got it working but if I resize the main window the view from the nib does not resize to the scrollview size so its width doesn't change and stays in the top left corner.

In the view that has the scroll view I have this simple code to load in the content from the nib file which is called DetailedView.swift:

```
self.detailedView = DetailedView(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
self.scrollView.documentView = self.detailedView.view
```

In the DetailedView I have the elements constrained to the view by adding top, leading and trailing constraints.

Anyone got any thoughts or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: How are you adding the view that contains the content to the scroll view, and how are you constraining it?

Comment: edited my question to show the code I'm using